# Using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 multiple classes like Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0, twitter-bootstrap-2

I was looking to find out what the equivalent of using multiple classes is in Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2. Currently Joomla 3 does not come with the latest version of Bootstrap which allows you to write the following in order to tackle different viewports.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
```

As i am new to bootstrap, I was wondering if I could do something similar using bootstrap 2.3.2 or is it best to target different viewports using media queries?

Apologies if its a simple question, but would like to know what can be made with the version I am using.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `spanX` classes like `col-X-X` classes natively.

But you can copy all CSS about `col-X-X` in Bootstrap 3, replace `col` with `span` in all selectors and use in your own CSS... I think should work.